# What to use instead of JSON, when payload is big in Restful API

Tags: json, web-services, rest, soap

I do have an existing JAVA based SOAP API and I a, trying to build a REST API instead.
JSON is not preferred for big payload.
[(How Big is Big for JSON)](http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/)

My Report generation API returns a XML payload ranging from *350kb* to *1MB*.

Not sure what the suggestion is.

### Question-

1. Should I go with REST/JSON or REST and something else?
2. Also what is the best design opinion for me to consider while moving from SOAP to RESTful
3. Any tools or framework, you may recommend?

Sorry if this is very open. I can provide more detail, if you suggest?

The technology I intend to use is all Java based

Comment: SOAP using XML is bigger than REST with JSON. So just go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well SOAP/XML is bigger in any case than a REST/JSON payload. Besides JSON works well even in this size range.

I would consider thinking your API from start while considering  [RESTful best practices](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tfpearsonecollege/bestpractices/RESTful+Best+Practices.pdf). JSON is simpler than SOAP and with some practice RESTful design will seem natural.

Finally in Java you may use [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services)

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: PBs are not meant to be used with large message sizes > 1MB, as advised here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#large-data